# MongoID: Group and Count

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Supposing I have a model `Post`, wich contains only the field `desc`.

The user can use hashtags, like `#rails` inside any posts...

How can I list and count the hashtags used, for example, in the last 10 days?

I'm do not know much about mongodb, but I see that I could use something called map_reduce.. have no idea why/how.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right...this can be solved using mad/reduce function...
try [this](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html#map_reduce) or this gem if you dont want to think a lot lol

https://github.com/jcoene/mongoid-mapreduce

Comment: hmm.. I think that should work. Tonight in my home I'll try it. Thanks by the way